# MongoDB: Not authorized on admin to execute command

Tags: mongodb, ubuntu, admin

My mongo shell is giving me this error when I am using `show dbs` command.

> not authorized on admin to execute command

I have tried to create a user using

```
db.createUser(
  {
    user: "siteUserAdmin",
    pwd: "password",
    roles: [ { role: "userAdminAnyDatabase", db: "admin" } ]
  }
)
```

as on https://docs.mongodb.com/v2.6/tutorial/add-user-administrator/

But it still gives me the same error:

> Could not add user: not authorized on admin to execute command.

I am using **Ubuntu 16.04** and **mongoDB** version is **3.4.9**

Answer (score 3):

I think you can use the role as root for Ubuntu. Try the below query.

```
use admin
db.createUser(
  {
    user: "admin",
    pwd: "password",
    roles: [ { role: "root", db: "admin" } ]
  }
);
exit;
```

You can give read write permission to user as well

```
use admin

 db.grantRolesToUser("admin",["readWrite"])
```

**EDIT**

Since the above didn't work try to start the instance with auth as below

1. Stop the mongod instance
2. Start the instance with `$ mongod --auth`
3. Now start mongo shell and create user

> ```
>    use admin
>    db.createUser(
>             {
>              user: "admin",
>              pwd: "password",
>              roles: [ { role: "root", db: "admin" } ]
>             }
>                 );
>            exit;
> ```

4. Now give permission

   > ```
   >  db.auth("admin", "password")
   >  db.grantRolesToUser("password", [ { role: "readWrite", db: "admin" } ])
   > ```
5. Now check `show users`

Comment: @SLASH what error you got exactly after executing with root

Comment: I got this error: **couldn't add user: not authorized on admin to execute command**

Comment: Here is the whole thing **Error: couldn't add user: not authorized on admin to execute command { createUser: "admin", pwd: "xxx", roles: [ { role: "root", db: "admin" } ], digestPassword: false, writeConcern: { w: "majority", wtimeout: 600000.0 } } :
_getErrorWithCode@src/mongo/shell/utils.js:25:13
DB.prototype.createUser@src/mongo/shell/db.js:1292:15
@(shell):1:1**

Comment: Same error: **Error: not authorized on admin to execute command { grantRolesToUser: "admin", roles: [ "readWrite" ], writeConcern: { w: "majority", wtimeout: 600000.0 } } :
_getErrorWithCode@src/mongo/shell/utils.js:25:13
DB.prototype.grantRolesToUser@src/mongo/shell/db.js:1493:19
@(shell):1:1**

Comment: `mongo --port 27017 -u "admin" -p "password" --authenticationDatabase "admin"` use command and run

Comment: It says Authentication failed

Comment: Nope didn't work. I started it with `mongod --auth`. Still gave me the same errors. I had to remove everything and reinstall everything and it works now